# Why not IO Unique an instance of Show and how to see what it is?

Tags: haskell, unique, monads, symbols

I am trying to use the Data.Unique in Haskell. 
The `newUnique` can generate an object, but I want to see what it is. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It generates an opaque, unique object different from all others in your program. You cannot look at it. You are allowed to hash it to an `Int` though:

```
import Data.Unique

main = do
    u <- newUnique
    print (hashUnique u)
```

Like so:

```
*Main> main
1
*Main> main
2
*Main> main
3
*Main> main
4
```

Comment: `import Data.Unique`
`import qualified Data.List as L `
`main = do`
    `u <- newUnique`
    `L.insert (hashUnique u) [2,3,4]`
Why can't this work?